# How do I query for a list of users who's column value aggregate matches a condition for a range of dates?

Tags: mysql, database, join

| user_id | app_open_events | day_utc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2021-05-01 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-05-01 |
| 1 | 0 | 2021-05-02 |
| 2 | 4 | 2021-05-02 |
| 1 | 0 | 2021-05-03 |
| 2 | 12 | 2021-05-03 |

Every day, a row for each user and how many app opens they did is added to this table. How can I run queries like "users who have a total of X app open events this week/month?" using this schema. For example, doing a query on 0 app opens for the month of May (05) on this dataset should yield `user_id` `1`

I have tried doing a join on several queries and I realize that I need to do some kind of join but I don't want the query to get needlessly complex. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far, its basic sql like GROUP BY.

Comment: I am confused on what to group by on - since the day_utc column takes in date format. If I do it for a date its useless, I want to be able to group by the month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement can be solved using `Extract` function and  'Having' clause

If you want 0 `app_open_events` in current week then use below query

```
select 
user_id  
from test 
where extract(week from day_utc)=extract(week from current_date)
group by user_id
having sum(app_open_events)=0   -- change the value as per your requirement
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=5f2275d232d89c2f84a1c2a1b5579daf)

For current month you can use following where clause

```
where extract(month from day_utc)=extract(month from current_date)
```

For any specific month you can use following where clause

```
where extract(month from day_utc)=5    --5 for may
```

For any specific date range you can use following where clause

```
where day_utc between '2021-03-01' and '2021-05-15'
```

Comment: THanks! I was using EXTRACT(MONTH FROM activity.day_utc) = 05 AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM activity.day_utc) = 2021 to get it for May

Can you explain why we're grouping on the user_id instead of the month?

Comment: I am grouping the user_id to calculate the sum of `app_open_events` which we are evaluating in `having` clause